# NoMethodError: undefined method `zone' for Time:Class

Tags: ruby, date, time, timezone, zone

How do i use Time.zone in ruby if I am not using rails
I want to do Time.now but that's available in rails but not ruby

I thought that

```
require 'time'
```

would fix this and make it available in ruby but it didn't and I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `zone' for Time:Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried to use zone as if it were a class method (`Time.zone`) [1]. If you want to use a class method:

```
1.9.3-p448 :007 > Time.now.zone
=> "EDT"
```

But `Time.now` is just a nice way of instantiating your own instance of `Time`[2]. So you're really just doing this (calling an instance method):

```
1.9.3-p448 :009 > time = Time.new
=> 2014-04-09 15:14:01 -0400 
1.9.3-p448 :010 > time.zone
=> "EDT"
```

[1] http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

[2] http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-now

Comment: Is Rubocop wrong? It suggests `Do not use Time.now without zone. Use Time.zone.now instead.`.

Comment: I was using Rails cops with my Rubocop config. `Time.zone.now` is a Rails-added thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, what do you mean. But I think it should work as below :

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> Time.now
=> 2014-04-09 23:19:04 +0530
>> Time.now.strftime('%Z')
=> "IST"
>> Time.now.strftime('%z')
=> "+0530"
>> Time.now.zone
=> "IST"
```

Documentation : [`#strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) and [`#zone`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-zone) .